# jQuery Mobile Changing Text Colour at Runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, mobile, text

I'm trying to change the text colour on a JQueryMobile button at runtime. I've been through many answers and tried a variety of items but it's not working for me. :(

It's the text colour of btnAnswer1 that I want to change the colour of.

I've tried the following, all with no luck.

```
$("#btnAnswer1").html('<color=green>Hello</color>');

$("#btnAnswer1").html(Hello);


$("#btnAnswer1").val("new text for button");


$('#btnAnswer1').children('.ui-btn').children('.ui-btn-c').children('.ui-shadow').children('.ui-corner-all').text("HELLO");


$('#btnAnswer1').val('Mark New');
$('#btnAnswer1').button('refresh');
```

Layout:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.css()` function of jQUery ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/)).

Something like the following will work: `$('#btnAnswer1').css('color', 'green')`.

Comment: This one had me foxed for a while this evening but you made it look easy. :)

Thank you very much, I do appreciate you taking the time to answer this question.

Comment: No problem! It's always nice to help people out ;)